# Authentication with phone number

Tags: android, libphonenumber

i am interested in logic of authentication by phone, i know a lot of services that offer user to authenticate with either phone or email during login, say Facebook. but what i am concerned about is that when you authenticate with phone on facebook it does not require you to put in country code and according to this [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_telephone_prefixes_by_country) lot of countries have same size of phone number, wouldn't it create problems for facebook if they could not determine country code of phone number, i know chances of this are slim but if two people from this type of countries which have same size of phone number digits, had the same password it would be a problem i reckon, so i know there is pretty good library called `libphonenumber-js`, can this library determine with 100% accuracy country code from given phone number without prefix (of country code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**libphonenumber-js** is a lib for validating and analyzing an international phone number and it doesn't auto detect country code

There are other ways to auto detect country f.e

```
val tm = applicationContext
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager 
val country = tm.simCountryIso
```

Comment: isn't this solely for android? there should be some universal way because FB is able to do it on the web a well

Comment: well I saw android tag so that's why I posted android snippet, However still facebook - or any website - can detect your country
just visit google.com and you'll see your country exposed on the footer

Comment: and by the way try using vpn to different country and facebook will not recognize your number without country code

Comment: I did not know that, thanks for the info, that seems logical.